# Run Angular 7 Web application offline with index.html

Tags: angular, web-applications, angular7, offline

Ehy guys i need an help, 
I want make an app demo for one of my customer.
This web application, will be open about index.html, and run offline.

In the web app there is only static and offline data. 
It's a demo to show the layout product.
I've already done the app, i was believe i found one mode to run offline, but i dind't :(

maybe running something:

```
ng build myproject --offline
```

My target is open the project offline with index.html

I've searched online but nothing. Can i run angular application offline with index.html ? 
Can you tell me how to do.
Thanks.

Comment: have a look at service workers  https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

Comment: Can i add on existing project ?

Comment: @David I have the same problem. How can I implement it in an existing project?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this with Angular is to use their PWA package. To do so, you can run the command `ng add @angular/pwa` if you have the latest Angular CLI. This package makes use of the technology Service Workers and allows you to preselected files to be served offline and the result of specific API endpoints. You will have a configuration JSON file to parameterize all of the features above mentioned.

You can find more information on their [website](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started).

Keep in mind that the Service Workers only work when served over HTTPS and to have it working with Angular, you have to build your app with the `--prod` flag.

Comment: what about when I want to publish it to make it work offline. Like for a demo purpose

Comment: The easiest way is to host it somewhere on the web that runs over HTTPS. You can use a free hosting provider or cloud service. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) have a free tier plan that is great for demos and prototypes but it's better to use any hosting services that you feel comfortable with.

Comment: @sebba23 it will work offline as soon as you set up properly your service workers and manifest

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work or not - move you build source to a cdn url and refer the path

Take a build as `ng build --prod --deploy-url=https://yoururl.com/`

This build will append the src url of all you js with the specified URL - once the build is done check the `index.html`

Now finally move all your build to your specified path - when you refer the path with `index.html` your application will be running

Hope this helps - happy coding :)